# Déclopé or Déclopée? What does the word mean?

Tags: sens, adjectifs

I've heard the word déclopé(e) three times this week and I don't know what it means and can't find it in any dictionary, although I did find éclopé.

Answer (score 2):

*Décloper* is used as a familiar term for "to stop smoking" (formed from *clope*, familiar word for cigaret).

*J'ai décidé de décloper* : I decided to stop smoking.

This is just hypothetical. If you are sure you heard well, maybe a bit of context would help.

Answer (score 2):

Il faudrait connaître le contexte, mais il semble bien qu'il s'agisse d'une

> bande *d'éclopés* !

synonyme de bande d'incapables.

**éclopé** (1176) de 'cloper'  boiter --> clopin-clopant : "Qui marche péniblement en raison d'un accident ou d'une blessure".
 *Un éclopé* : "soldat légèrement blessé".

 synonymes : boiteux, estropié, infirme. [Le Robert]

Comment: +1 Bien plus plausible que l'improbable verbe "décloper".

Comment: Comme la personne avait trouvé "éclopé" dans un dictionnaire sans être satisfaite, j'ai cherché plus compliqué. Je ne nie pas que le mot soit peu courant, mais vous seriez surpris du nombre de résultats google correspondants.

Comment: @Jhyn C'est bien pour cela que tout dépend du contexte : phonétiquement *d'éclopé(s)* est le plus usité, mais *décloper* peut être une invention née de l'arrivée de la cigarette électronique (qui reste malgré tout *une clope que l'on vaporette*)